# How to use msdeploy to rebind website to new subfolder

Tags: asp.net, iis, deployment

I want to deploy new releases to separate subfolders and then rebind the same application to the new subfolder.

I already know how to deploy content to specific folder:
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:package=C:\agent_work\r11\a\projectX\website-package.zip -dest:contentPath=\server\projectX$\releaseXYZ

Now I only need to notify IIS to rebind the app to the new subfolder.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy" -verb:sync -source:apphostconfig="DestSiteName",computername=myserveraddress -dest:auto,computername=myserveraddress -setParam:type=DestinationVirtualDirectory,scope="DestSiteName",value=D:\destiantionPath -disableLink:ContentExtension
```

This will change destination dir without deploying files